# If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary $m\times n$ matrices, show that $^t(A+B)= {}^tA+{}^tB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm reading Lang's: *Introduction to Linear Algebra*.

There is this exercise:

> If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary $m\times n$ matrices, show that $^t(A+B)= {}^tA+{}^tB$

I did the following:

$${}^t(A_{ij}+B_{ij})$$

As the sum of matrices adds $a_{ij}+b_{ij}$ component-wise, then:

$${}^t((A+B)_{ij})$$

And then, the transposition does: $a_{ij}\mapsto {}^t a_{ji}$

I have:

$${}^t((A+B)_{ij})=(A+B)_{ji}$$

Reversing what I did in step $1,2$:

$$(A+B)_{ji}=A_{ji}+B_{ji}$$

Now checking the RHS:

$${}^t(A_{ij})+{}^t(B_{ij})=A_{ji}+B_{ji}$$

Exactly as wanted. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct proof.

Comment: Same here I believe it's correct.